# How to access a Google Sheet from an API executed in a browser window.

Tags: google-sheets-api

I have google sheet and would like to access the content via api from a browser window. The range would be EGK!A1:G8 as an example.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mJaSiWljYu11PGJamaV98-hgiwFBDxuoRjtwOfC4kXo/edit?usp=sharing/

I tried 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mJaSiWljYu11PGJamaV98-hgiwFBDxuoRjtwOfC4kXo/edit?usp=sharing/values/SBR!A1%3AG8' but in vain.

Comment: I just want to get the json format of the spreadsheet content

Answer (score 0):

I am now able to get the JSON format but it has too many values...Would be nice to have the content only rather than the 3 objects: version, encoding, and feed

https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1mJaSiWljYu11PGJamaV98-hgiwFBDxuoRjtwOfC4kXo/2/public/full?alt=json